# How to detect when a user leaves a certain tab in a JTabbedPane

Tags: java, jtabbedpane

I know how to write a ChangeListener that records the index of the newly selected tab in a JTabbedPane, but what I want is to detect when a user leaves a certain tab. I have 7 tabs, and I would like to run some code when the user leaves tab number 6. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the focus state. You can check with `component.hasFocus()` or the `getSelectedIndex` method. This depends on how your components are accessible or how you implemented your TabbedPane

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here:
[Java JTabbedPane - Action immediately before changing the selected Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37913932/java-jtabbedpane-action-immediately-before-changing-the-selected-tab).
All I had to do was create a new class that extended DefaultSingleSelectionModel. The class overrides the setSelectedIndex() method.

```
public class MySingleSelectionModel extends DefaultSingleSelectionModel {
    @Override
    public void setSelectedIndex(int index) {
        if (getSelectedIndex() == 6) {
            //perform action here
        }
        super.setSelectedIndex(index);
    }
}
```

Finally, I set the model in the JTabbedPanel:

```
myTabbedPane.setModel(new MySingleSelectionModel());
```